# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '514026847680593922'

Tags: python, discord.py

So i was trying to make a command for seeing the lvl and xp for a user and this is what i coded

```
@client.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

but it always gives an erorr

```
Ignoring exception in command level:
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\shit_2.py", line 65, in level
    lvl = users[str(user.id)]['level']
KeyError: '514026847680593922'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '514026847680593922'
```

someone please help

Edit:-
this is how my json file looks

```
{"<@514026847680593922>": {"experience": 95, "level": 3}}
```

Comment: What does your json file look like ? Could you paste it as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if somewhere in your code you write in the json a new user, for example when someone join the server.

The traceback simply says that Python cannot find the entry '514026847680593922' in your users variable (that is the data from the json)

When that happens, maybe you should `users[str(member.id)] = {"level": 0, "experience": 0}` and save that to the json file and then try again

Comment: its not working and giving the same error